# In this sentence, how can 'where' be interpreted?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> You can have a virus where people feel well enough while they’re infectious that they get on a plane or they go to a market.

I can't understand a structure of this sentence. What do 'where' and 'that' do and how should I understand them?

It's from a TED video, 'The next outbreak? We’re not ready' in 4:20.
https://youtu.be/6Af6b_wyiwI?t=260

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Check this question and see whether you think that it answers your question. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/237299/found-myself-being-in-a-situation-where-i-feel-like

Answer (score 1):

> *You can have a virus* [*where people feel well enough while they’re*
> *infectious* [*that they get on a plane or they go to a market* ]].

The element in outer brackets is a relative clause introduced by the relative word "where", which has "virus" as antecedent.

Within the relative clause is the embedded content (*that*) clause, in inner brackets, which functions as an indirect complement, licensed by "enough".

Answer (score 0):

As to the meaning, here's a paraphrase:

- The virus creates a situation in which infected people feel well enough to go out in public.

Relative "where" can refer to a characteristic of a location (*the hill where you can see the bay*, *the room where I left my jacket*), but also to a characteristic of a situation (*the episode where Joey loses his wallet*). A virus (i.e. a viral epidemic) is a situation.